# Show elements dynamically in a zend form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

i am using zend form and i have a condition such that:

when i select a value of a dropdown, i have to show a text field dynamically below the dropdown field.

And when i select another value of a dropdown, i have to show another field dynamically below the dropdown field.

I want to use ajax with onchange event of the dropdown field... how can i go ahead ?

This is my sample code of element creation in zend form:

```
$country = $this->createElement('select',’countries’);
            $country ->setLabel('Countries:')
                ->addMultiOptions(array(
                        'US' => 'United States',
                        'UK' => 'United Kingdom' 
                            ))
                ->setAttrib('id', 'country');
```

Comment: Why ajax? you cannot just make them all, set their ccs display to none, and use e.g. JQuery to show/hide an element based on the option selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$country = $this->createElement('select',’countries’);
            $country ->setLabel('Countries:')
                ->addMultiOptions(array(
                        'US' => 'United States',
                        'UK' => 'United Kingdom' 
                            ))
                ->setAttrib('id', 'country');
                ->setAttrib('onchange', 'javascript goes here that will set textbox to visible'
$textbox = $this->createElement('text',’textbox’);
            $textbox->setAttrib('style', 'display:none;')
            ->setAttrib('id', 'country');
```

Comment: Thanks, in my javascript, i am writing like: $("#state").show(); and $("#state").hide(); based on the selected value of the country dropdown.

Comment: doesn't work if there is a label associated with the element... the labels is sitll shown... :(